# can we display both AdMob native and banner ads at the same activity?

Tags: admob, native, ads, banner

Can you show both banner ads and native ads on the same activity? Is it against AdMob policy?

Comment: you can have them in same activity as long as you follow these guidelines https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6240814?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I make simple android app with admob. so, can I use both native and banner at a time in the same activity?